# Android: showing dialogFrag on adapter gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to open a dialogFragment through an adapter, I've been all over the documentation and other questions, I can't find the problem. This is the full error line from the log `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.FragmentManager android.app.Activity.getFragmentManager()' on a null object reference`

**My adapter:**

```
public class SubjectsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubjectsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    public Activity mcontext;

    public SubjectsAdapter(Activity context) {
        this.mcontext=context.getParent();
        assert mcontext != null;

    }

//...usual adapter code here...

    static int i;

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public Button GridButton;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            GridButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_button);

            GridButton.setId(++i);
            GridButton.setText("Button " + i);

            assert GridButton != null;
            GridButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //removeItem(getAdapterPosition());
                    Fragment_Subject_Edit newFragment = Fragment_Subject_Edit.newInstance();
                    newFragment.show(mcontext.getFragmentManager(), "Title");
                }
            });  
        }
    }       
}
```

**the DialogFragment:**

```
     public static Fragment_Subject_Edit newInstance() {

        return new Fragment_Subject_Edit();
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subject_edit, null));

        return builder.create();
    }
```

Ok so what am I missing here to show my DialogFragment when I click in the GridButton?

Comment: What happens if you just assign `mcontext = context;`? Any particular reason you are currently using `mcontext=context.getParent();`?

Comment: Okay, it worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this line:

```
newFragment.show(mcontext.getFragmentManager(), "Title");
```

You are asking to mcontext for the fragmentManager and your problem is that at that point mcontext is null. Like George said, unless you really need it, just set the context straight ahead instead of its parent, thats a potential cause of the Null.

Comment: Ok that worked, but quick question, if I'm not setting `.getParent` which context am I getting on `mcontext`exactly ?

Comment: Well that depends in which parameter you are passing to the `SubjectsAdapter` object upon construction. My guess is that you are creating it from your main activity and passing `this` as parameter, if that's the case then you are getting your activity context.

Comment: Yea you guessed right, thanks for the explanation =)

Answer (score 0):

try using following code after including the Pop library in your gradle dependencies. you wont even need to implement method `onCreateDialog`

add this in your app module gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.vistrav:pop:2.0'
}
```

and your class with be simple as like this

```
public class SubjectsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubjectsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    public Activity mcontext;

    public SubjectsAdapter(Activity context) {
        this.mcontext=context.getParent();
        assert mcontext != null;

    }

//...usual adapter code here...

    static int i;

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public Button GridButton;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            GridButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grid_button);

            GridButton.setId(++i);
            GridButton.setText("Button " + i);

            assert GridButton != null;
            GridButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Pop.on(mcontext).with().title("Title").body(R.layout.fragment_subject_edit).show();
                }
            });  
        }
    }       
}
```

you won't need any more code to build dialog after this. you can check more detail of this library [here](https://github.com/00ec454/pop)